# c# WPF - remove double click event from data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a data grid that the user can insert inputs to one of the columns (password).
I want to prevent a user from double clicking on the data grid.
how can i disable this event ?

```
 <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData}" ItemsSource="{Binding CbVendorItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVendor}"
                             MinWidth="100"  MaxHeight="Infinity" Margin="10,5,10,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontFamily="../Fonts/#GeForce-Bold" 
                 Visibility="{Binding VendorVis}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Release?" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Password" Binding="{Binding PasswordTextInput}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="150">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ProgressBar  Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}"  Visibility="{Binding ProgressVis}" Background="#FF1A1A1A" BorderBrush="#FF76B900" Margin="2"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="%" Visibility="{Binding ProgressVis}" Binding="{Binding ProgressPercent}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="File Passed" Binding="{Binding FilePassed}" Width="*" Visibility="{Binding ProgressVis}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: [DataGridColumn.IsReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.isreadonly?view=windowsdesktop-6.) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `DataGrid.IsReadOnly` to `true`, if your intention is to prevent the user from editing any cell:

```xml
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" />
```

To prevent the user from editing a particular column, set the `DataGridColumn.IsReadOnly` of this column to `true`:

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" />
```

To disable mouse interaction in general, you can set `DataGrid.IsHitTestVisible` to `false`. This will also disable row/cell selection:

```xml
<DataGrid IsHitTestVisible="False" />
```